# How can I ensure swift will return an result expression type to my expected result type?

Tags: swift, return-type

I am experimenting with result types ie: `Result<Int, Error>` in Swift.

In my code I am wanting to try to do a numeric addition to a player's funds captured as `Int` and do some validation.

For example: `Add 1 coin to balance` and return any validation error.

I use a result type to return a success or fail, depending on whether or not it has hit the validation or not.

However, in Swift the compiler complains that it cannot convert return type to the expected type (actual error message shown later on).

I think its because the function is returning an enum, and not the actual result type.

The code I am using is below, and edited to reflect the specific function I am testing.

The code is meant to allow a balance, or funds to be "credited" or "debited", however, in the following only discusses the specific function causing the error

```
// code follows... 

public enum FundingError: Error {
    case notEnough(funds: Int)
    case mustBePositive
}

public struct Funds {
    static func credit(balance: Int, with amount: Int) -> Result<Int, FundingError> {
        return Transaction.make(.credit(balance: balance, withAmount: amount))
    }
    // debit is omitted for now
}


private enum Transaction {
    case credit(balance: Int, withAmount: Int)
    case debit(balance: Int, byAmount: Int)
    
    func make(t: Transaction) -> Result<Int, FundingError> {
        do {
            let _ = try Transaction.validate(t)
                        
            switch self {
            case .credit(let balance, let amount):
                var balance = balance
                balance += amount
                return .success(balance)
                            
            case .debit(let balance, let amount):
                  // debit code removed for now
                return .success(balance)
            }
        }
        catch let err {
            return .failure(err as! FundingError)
        }
    }
    
}
```

The validator does the following, again edited only to show the credit bit

```
extension Transaction {
    static func validate(_ transaction: Transaction) throws {
        switch (transaction) {
            
        case .credit(_, let amount):
            guard amount > 0 else {
                throw FundingError.mustBePositive
            }
        // debit case would go here
    }      
}
```

The compiler error is being thrown on this line:

`return Transaction.make(.credit(balance: balance, withAmount: amount))`

stating,

> Cannot convert return expression of type '(Transaction) -> Result<Int,
> FundingError>' to return type 'Result<Int, FundingError>'

Why does this happen, and how do I ensure that it converts the correct result type?

With thanks

Comment: Is `make` supposed to be `static`? Is this just a typo?

Comment: I will try it, i guess it does make sense to be static

Comment: Thank you, after some quick edits and changes the error has gone away.   Additionally, I was able to write a quick xctest of adding 1 coin too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to convert the `make` function static, this did have some other impacts in the code, but I was able to rectify them.

Additionally, I was able to do a quick xctest of adding 1 coin,

```
func testDidAddCreditOf1() throws {
        let result = Funds.credit(balance: 0, with: 1)

        guard case .success(let value) = result else {
            return XCTFail("Expected to be a success but got a failure with \(result)")
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(value, 1)
    }
```

With thanks/credit to @Sweeper for pointing this out.